# How to determine the severity or size of a hole in yard?

Tags: backyard, sinkhole

I found a hole in my yard. This area has three common features that could cause that, a sink hole from an underground stream, prairie dogs, which are everywhere in the neighborhood, or an abandoned mine shaft. For safety reasons, I need to determine how large the hole is. It is 4 ft from the property line, so I also want to know how much of my property is endangered, but want to be careful examining the hole, as it could be more on the neighbors side (it does point that direction), and so disturbing it could undermine their property.

What can I do to determine the size of the hole?

Comment: Is this a new hole? Call your city/county inspector and have them examine it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is new. I moved in recently, and noticed it after.

Comment: Any portion of the hole that is under your neighbours property is not your problem, it's theirs. as an interested party they may be willing to offer advice as to what type of hole this appears to be.

Comment: Measure the perimeter and divide by 3.14 to get the diameter.

Comment: use the same technique that you used to determine the distance from the property line .... use a tape measure to get exact dimensions if you so desire

Comment: I think you should probe the hole with a plumbing probing rod. These come in 3', 4', and 5' lengths and have a T handle. Also talk to your neighbor about your shared problem.

Comment: Define "hole" -  does it go straight down?  did you dig up some topsoil & found a horizontal shaft?   How far below ground level is this hole or  cavity?

Comment: You could add bomb shelter somewhere one was found from a hole in the ground. A photo of the area might give a clue.

Comment: i don't think you need to measure to figure the difference between a sinkhole, a mineshaft, and prairie dogs; they are all orders of magnitude different size.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the previous owner's dog revealed it, I just moved some things and found it. The dog's hole is 2ft down, then the cavity is found.

Comment: @JACK If I report it to the city, does that open me up to having to reveal the problem when I sell it, so if it is a sink hole, I'd have to sell the property at a huge loss?

Comment: I'm not an attorney but i think you're obligated to inform buyers of any problems. How would you feel if you didn't tell them and some little kid fell down and was hurt or killed.  Is your yard fenced in?  You're responsible since it's on your property.